# How to increase Bootstrap 3 Navbar height while keeping menu height small when collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to increase the height of a top-fixed Bootstrap 3 navbar to 80px, but want to keep the original min-height at 50px, when the menu is collapsing (i.e. screen widths of less than 768px).

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Project</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Support</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
<!-- Navigation Bar End -->
</div>
```

I am using the following CSS and succesfully changed the navbar height, but the collapsed menu height is still at 80px:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
min-height: 80px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar {
border-radius: 4px;
min-height: 50px;
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your logic is backwards. Right now it'll only apply that 50px height for pages WIDER than 768px.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I finally developed a solution myself. You have to create a media query that keeps the line height of the collapsing menu at 20px for screen widths up to 767px. The following CSS in my style.css overrides the boostrap.css and solved my problem:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 80px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;}
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I only needed 60px, but still great answer. The 60px for me was perfect for a better view of the brand logo I'm using.

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is backwards. Right now it'll only apply that 50px height for pages WIDER than 768px. This should fix it:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 80px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: 50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it. Same issue.

Comment: Tried it with your edited code and still not working. Any other idea how to get this working?

Comment: You want the entire 'navbar' to be 50px, or individual menu items?

Comment: I want the entire fixed navbar to be always 90px, but the collapsed lower part of the menu (i.e. for screenresolutions lower than 768px) to be 50px, while the top-part stays at 90px.