# Bootstrap Navbar height as logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, navigationbar

I've created a navbar with a logo but the logo is out of place (see image). I know how to shrink the image so it fits the navbar, but **I want to increase the height of the navigation bar so that it matches the logo**.

[image]

This is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Mobtech </title>

        <!--Ubaci bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-container">
                        <span class="sr-only"> Pokazi i sakrij navigaciju </span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="Slike/logo.png" alt="LogoSlika"/>
                    </a>
                </div> 
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"> Početna strana </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Privatni korisnici </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Poslovni korisnici </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Uređaji </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> O Nama </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <br />
            <!-- JavaScript fajl -->
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Kompresovan JavaScript fajl -->
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I don't have my custom CSS. Do I need to create it ? I'm new to bootstrap.

Comment: Add your css for .navbar-brand{}

Comment: link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553572/how-to-increase-bootstrap-3-navbar-height-while-keeping-menu-height-small-when-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as that: add this line near including boostrap.min.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Create a new file named **style.css** in css folder, and add this lines in it.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a  {
    padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

I've tested it and worked for me 100%.

Comment: This works but I have one problem. Only the active class (Pocetna Strana) is aligned in the middle. The other li elements are not aligned well. I screenshot the problem: https://s22.postimg.org/f39ji8gi9/pro2.png 
And this is the mobile version: https://s13.postimg.org/51c7pqatz/pro4.png

Comment: Check now. Just remove .active class

Comment: Thanks @dragos.bad ! Works great ! But the mobile version is still off: https://s13.postimg.org/51c7pqatz/pro4.png

Comment: Provide a photo of what you want to be and i will show the css for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 80px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This special code works for me with a similar problem with resizing navbar-inverse. I placed the code in my bootstrap custom CSS. You can change the padding to fit hover nav color blocks. For the image issues (site logo) you can add a style="margin-top/bottom, left, right: -12px or 12px" to the

Thanks